# Weblogic LDAP error address in use

Tags: weblogic

I am getting an error like the following with Weblogic 10.3.6 when I try to start a managed server:

```
Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAPException: Unable to open     
initial replica url: http://<host ip>:<admin port>/bea_wls_management_internal2/wl_management
weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAPException: Unable to open initial replica url: http://<host ip>:<admin port>/bea_wls_management_internal2/wl_management
    at weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAP.getInitialReplicaFromAdminServer(EmbeddedLDAP.java:1388)
    at weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAP.start(EmbeddedLDAP.java:251)
```

That is followed by a bind exception with address already in use. I ran netstat and that address is definitely not in use for this box. The only thing running is the node manager. Any ideas?

I've googled around a bit and tried removing the ldap, cache, and tmp folder with no luck. The host ip and port are correct, I can bring up the admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key is the address in use exception, not the replica URL problem.

My guess (and I have made this mistake before) is you are trying to start the managed server on the wrong host. If not, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Doh! I feel so stupid, you were right. I tried to start the managed server manually (startManagedServer.sh) on the wrong host.

Answer (score 1):

The managed server at startup communicates with the admin server to get a copy of the LDAP.
The unable to open initial replica ... means the managed server is not able to connect to the admin server on the ip:port that you provided via the startup script.

check the admin server is up and running before starting the managed server.
Make sure you are starting the managed server from the correct domain / folder.